# Swift app cant connect to internet when distributed via .ipa

Tags: ios, swift, connection, ipa

I am developing an app, when the app is installed on my device it works fine, never had any connectivity issues. I added a UDID of a beta tester, updated the provisioning profile and sent him the a link to download the .ipa via manifest etc...

If I download the app via the AWS S3 server its being hosted on, it works fine. However, if my beta tester downloads the app it installs and loads, but wont connect to the internet. Note: Under settings > general there isn't an option for device management to allow the app on EITHER of our devices, because this isn't an enterprise app.

I have researched and tried to duplicate the issue to no end. We both have the same model phone (X) and same version of iOS.

Update: tried an Ad-Hoc provisioning profile with no changes to results

Comment: "updated the provisioning profile"  Which one is THE provisioning profile?

Comment: I dont understand the question, but the provisioning profile is created on the developer portal of the account on apples website and is used to "sign the app" when exporting...

Comment: I suggest you learn about provisioning profiles before referring to yours with 'the provisioning profile.'

Comment: I understand the question now, you are asking which type of provisioning profile I was using. I was using a development profile, but now thinking an Ad-Hoc may be more appropriate?

Comment: Update: tried an Ad-Hoc provisioning profile with no changes to results.

Comment: Maybe a shot in the dark, but to what kind of URLs are you trying to speak in the app? HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: both. Firebase and an http api server. Neither work on my buddies device, however like said, both connections work fine on my device.